# Prove or disprove the law of double pseudo-complements hold for subgraphs?

Tags: abstract-algebra, graph-theory, lattice-orders, algebraic-graph-theory, universal-algebra

As for the categories of subgraphs of a given graph $X$ with their inclusions, we have a co-Heyting algebra (and Heyting algebra).

In the co-Heyting algebra, we define $\sim$$A$ as the pseudo-complement of a subgraph A as follows: it is the smallest subgraph whose union with A is equal to the whole given graph, in symbol $\sim$$A\vee$$A=X$.

I'm wondering whether the double pseudo-complement $\sim$$(\sim$$A)=A$ holds or not. I have a difficulty in either of proving $\sim$$(\sim$$A)=A$ or providing a counter example.
Based on a few *experiments* in my notepad, it seems that $\sim$$(\sim$$A)=A$ may hold.

My question is, does $\sim$$(\sim$$A)=A$ hold? If so, how can I prove it? If not, can I have a counter example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true; the double pseudo-complement will erase any “isolated” node from the original subgraph. Consider (undirected) 3-cycle (or complete graph on $3$ nodes) $C_3$ with set of vertices $V=\{0,1,2\}$, and take the subgraph $A:=(V,\{\{0,1\}\})$. Then ${\sim} A=(V,\{\{0,2\},\{1,2\}\})$ and ${\sim}{\sim} A=(\{0,1\},\{\{0,1\}\})$.

Comment: Nice example! Then, if a subgraph is connected (i.e., there is a path from any point to any other point in the graph), is this true in general? (probably I think we need to assume the given graph $X$ is also connected.)

Comment: @Pengin As far as I've checked, you only need $A$ to have no isolated points. Connectedness seems to be overkill.

Comment: Thx. I'll try to prove it in this week!